# Building a HubL template with an array of objects editable by user in page edit

Tags: html, jinja2, hubspot

I'm trying to build a Hubl Template which my client can use to add additional podcast episodes to a list in page edit. I'm able to generate the code with a Hubl Template like so:

```
{% set episodes = [{
  id: "1", 
  date: "9/12/16"
},{
  id: "2", 
  date: "9/12/16"
},{
  id: "3"
  date: "9/12/16"
},{
  id: "4", 
  date: "9/12/16"
}]%}

{% for episode in episodes %}
  <h2 class="podcast-title">Episode {{episode.id}}</h2>
  <h4 class="podcast-date">{{episode.date}}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

My problem is that I don't want to have my client come into the page template every time to add additional episodes. I want the episodes to be editable by the "page edit" page.

I am able to do this with single images like so:

```
{% image "hero_image" label='Select a hero image', 
src='imageurl', no_wrapper=True,
export_to_template_context=True %}
```

But I don't know how or if it is possible to do this with an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered creating a separate "blog" in their HubSpot portal specifically for Podcasts?  It may be labeled a blog, but it works well for managing any regular-cadence published content.

If that's not an option, I'd recommend using a Flexible Column in your template layout and using a custom module for each podcast.

- [How do Flexible Columns work](https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-do-flexible-columns-work)
- [Creating Custom Modules](http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/cos/custom-modules)

This way, as your client is editing a page to post a new podcast, he/she can add any module desired to the flexible column -- you'll need to teach how to find+add your Podcast listing module, but it can't be any harder than you were attempting with template code :)

Comment: Hey Kirk, Yes I have thought about creating a blog I was just trying to make this work before giving into that option. The custom module method isn't a bad idea either but I always had trouble with the modules being locked/uneditable in the page edit section. Thank you for all the help today.

Comment: Hmm... should work!  May need to start with a WYSIWYG Template and convert it to code.  I had a similar challenge setting a client up with a highly-specialized image gallery.  We used a custom module inside a flex column where they added every image/portfolio item, and the page took care of the rest.

Comment: Last comment -- it's client-side scripted (likely not SEO friendly), but here's a COS hackathon winner using Google Sheets to manage data and display a slicker eComm-esque user experience. http://www.bluleadz.com/chad-pierce-hackathon-2-submision

Comment: The custom modules worked exactly for what I needed. I was thinking of group-modules which I use to try and use for the job of custom modules but always found them to be locked in page edit. Thanks again for your help!